# How to implement a two-level beta regression?

Tags: time-series, multilevel-analysis, cross-section, beta-regression

I am working with Time-series Cross-section data and my response variable is a proportion ranging from 0 to 1 (including 0 values but no 1s observed).

Beta regressions, and especially the `fracreg` (since I have 0s) command in Stata, seem most appropriate. However if there exists the possibility to cluster data by one variable, I can't find a way to cluster by two variables (country and date).

Does anyone know how to go about it?